# Doctrine Persist Data into Database with Console Command

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I created the console command but during the execution I get the following error:

```
In ControllerTrait.php line 338:

  Call to a member function has() on null
```

**DatabaseHelper.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Currency;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Controller\CurrencyComparison;

class DatabaseHelper extends AbstractController
{
    public function insertValues()
    {
        $curFromAPI = new CurrencyComparison();
        $curFromAPI = $curFromAPI->compareCurrencies();

        $date = new \DateTime('@'.strtotime('now'));
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $currency = new Currency();
        $currency->setName('USD');
        $currency->setAsk($curFromAPI->getUSD());
        $currency->setLastUpdated($date);
        $entityManager->persist($currency);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

**CurrencyComparison.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

use App\Service\DatabaseHelper;

class CurrencyComparison extends Command
{
    private $databaseHelper;

    public function __construct(DatabaseHelper $databaseHelper){
        $this->$databaseHelper = $databaseHelper;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {

        $this
            ->setName('app:currency-comparison')
            ->setDescription('Inserts currencies into the database.')
            ->setHelp('Compares currencies from APIs and inserts the lower rates into the database.')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->databaseHelper->insertValues();

        $output->writeln([
            'Currencies are being inserted into the database',
            '============',
            '',
        ]);

        $output->writeln('Done.');
    }
}
```

When debugging, noticed that I'm getting this error after the following line in DatabaseHelper.php:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

What should I change or should be looking for?

Thanks.

--UPDATE--
I created a Service and tried to inject EntityManager as construct.

**App/Service/DatabaseHelper.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;


class DatabaseHelper extends AbstractController
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function insertValues()
    {

        $curFromAPI = new CurrencyComparison();
        $curFromAPI = $curFromAPI->compareCurrencies();

        $date = new \DateTime('@'.strtotime('now'));
        $this->entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        return dd($curFromAPI);
        $currency = new Currency();
        $currency->setName('USD');
        $currency->setAsk($curFromAPI->getUSD());
        $currency->setLastUpdated($date);
        $entityManager->persist($currency);

        // actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
        $entityManager->flush();

     }
}
```

and updated Command\CurrencyComparison.php too. But when I'm trying to call execute function on CurrencyComparison.php, I cannot reach its' `$this->databaseHelper->insertValues();` function. Would you mind to give any suggestions?

--UPDATE & Solution--

- Removed extends AbstractController from class DatabaseHelper.
- Changed __construct of DatabaseHelper and injected as follows: `(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)`
- removed the following line from insertValues function in DatabaseHelper.php:
  `$this->entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` and just used persist and flush functions as like above.

Comment: You are close but you still don't quite get it.  You inject the entity manager which is great but then you are still using $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()...  See the problem?  Just use $this->entityManager->persist and flush.  And get rid of the AbstractController nonsense completely.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I'll check this one now.

Comment: @Cerad it's fine now. I had to take a break probably. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your command has a dependency on `DatabaseHelper` that has a dependency on the `Entity Manager`, create the `DatabaseHelper` class as a service, with the `Entity manager` injected in via its constructor (autowire it, or specify in its service definition).

then, as per the [docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html) you can inject your `DatabaseHelper` service into the command via the constructor as it'll it be autowired by default.

I would also consider **not** extending the `AbstractController` as your `DatabaseHelper` is very tight in scope and wont need the entire container (assuming its only what youve posted).  Just inject what you need.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check this and send feedback marking as answer.

Comment: I've updated the post, added DatabaseHelper.php as a service (by creating a new file) and followed up the documentation. Where do I go wrong?